# Rounding in Google Sheets to match a SUM value in a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell that returns a result that I need to split as percentages over 5 other cells that still need to add together to equal the original cell value. Rounding in sheets seems to make them add up wrong.

When I format the cell back to no decimal places - I want to show a whole number - they all round up and then total 24, but I need it to be the same as B1.
B1 is returned based on a formula so it will change depending on what is input into the other cells.

[Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xv0U5YYq4pW7UsigfqCjXhrrrctCXMAvpSfifFO0PsQ/edit)

Comment: Split into 5 pieces but only use 4. Calculate the 5th as the difference between the original and the sum of the 4.

Comment: "Google Sheets"? So why the `excel` tag?

Comment: Can you show us your sheet, or at least the formulas you're using?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xv0U5YYq4pW7UsigfqCjXhrrrctCXMAvpSfifFO0PsQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: why isn't B9 formula  = B3-B8  ?

Comment: The workings behind this is all done in pounds as I have adapted it of an American sheet. The people who will be using this deal in metrics so I needed to convert some of the results to kilograms. Hopefully that makes sense. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the link to the demo spreadsheet and to make cell references in the body of the question match the structure of the demo spreadsheet. By the other hand all the relevant details should be included explicitly on the question like that you are using cell formatting for rounding.